# Ajax or Jquery Search Result on rails 2.3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to make my search user friendly by using jquery or ajax. I'm using searchlogic for my query and a basic search submission.

My search form is the same page as the result. So If I submit the search, the page will reload and show the result under the form.

Search Form:

```
<% form_tag search_path do %>
 <% text_field_tag :name %>
<% end %>

<%= result %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => { :action => "search"}, :update => "result" do %>
<% text_field_tag :name %>
<% end %>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using rails 2.3 some syntax I can't use